# Laravel seed create wrong number of rows in DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-6.2

I'm trying to create a seeder with relationships

```
public function run()
{
    factory(Company::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($company){
        $company->buildings()->saveMany(factory(Building::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($building){
            $building->facilities()->saveMany(factory(App\Models\Facility::class,5)->make());
        }));
    });
}
```

That code should creeate 10 companies and 5 buildings for each company and 5 facilities for each building. 
companies 10
buildings 50
facilities 250

but I get

companies 300
buildings 310
facilties 250
which doesn't make sense

my factories:

```php
$factory->define(Company::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $name = $faker->lastName;
    $company = $name.' Company';
    return [
        'name' => $company,
        'shortName' => $name
    ];
});
```

```php
$factory->define(Building::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Hotel '.$faker->lastName,
        'company_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Models\Company::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

```php
$factory->define(Facility::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $elements = array('lavabo','ducha');

    return [
        'name' => $faker->randomElement($elements).' '.$faker->numerify('Habitacion ###'),
        'building_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Models\Building::class)->create()->id;
        }
    ];
});
```

And the databaseSeeder.php

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CompaniesSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The problem comes from here:

```php
$company->buildings()->saveMany(factory(Building::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($building){
    $building->facilities()->saveMany(factory(App\Models\Facility::class,5)->make());
}));
```

Every time you create a new building, and facility, it is creating a new company in your factory as well.

Simply pass the appropriate parameters to your `create` function to let Faker know to not create new company and building.

Change from:

```php
factory(Building::class, 5)->create()
```

To:

```php
factory(Building::class, 5)->create(['company_id' => $company->id]);
```

And apply the same logic for `Facility`.

```php
factory(App\Models\Facility::class,5)->make(['building_id' => $building->id])
```

### Side note

You can also simplify your factories by replacing your callback function like this:

```php
$factory->define(Building::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => 'Hotel '.$faker->lastName,
        'company_id' => factory(Company::class),
    ];
});
```